# Size limit of .html and .gs files (Google Apps Script)

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-docs

I am developing an add-on for Google Docs, and I am planning on hosting my database of multiple (tens) html files of varying lines and sizes. One html file contains about 6250 lines, for example. I tried saving another big html file but I always get ***"We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again"*** after I hit the save button. However, I was wondering about the maximum size of the html files for Google Apps Script. And whether it is a good idea to have my entire database stored in several html files to increase speed since it is already up there. Your help and advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Does the complete data need to be loaded often?  Or can users load smaller sets of data?  Do you filter, sort, sum, etc. the data?  Is this data displayed in tables, or is it a text document?

Comment: I suspect that your problem is one of size, but I don't know what the specific limits are - but in my opinion you're well past what I'd trust to GAS. If it's a database you need, wouldn't it make sense to use an actual database? Or provide part of the service as a hosted web service, with the add-on providing UI and abstraction only?  I can't imagine you'll get good performance searching through GAS-hosted html files, especially as the entire script (all files) will be loaded into a new execution instance for each invocation, and put through caja sanitization etc.

Comment: @SandyGood the whole data only needs to be loaded once the add-on is installed. It is presented as text that needs to be manipulated, filtered, and sorted.

Comment: @Mogsdad Thank you for the advice. I was planning on providing part of the service as a hosted web service and have the add-on connect the two parts. However, I thought that having the database stored in separate html files where the add-on files are stored will be of efficiency and convenience. Thank you for the enlightenment, again.

Comment: You can create an HTML file and save it in the Drive of the account that the Apps Script belongs to.  I'm assuming that the HTML file that you are now using is **internal** to Apps Script.  Instead of making it internal to  Apps Script, create a file and retrieve it with Drive Service, or Docs Service.  You could even break the file up into a couple of smaller files.  As long as the users computer can handle the data, I don't think that whether you get the data in one big chunk or smaller chunks that it will affect performance.